# clear out the complete signature in one click

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am using [jSignature](https://willowsystems.github.io/jSignature/#/about/) on my web page. This jquery plugin deletes one stroke at a time. I want behavior of "Undo last stroke" to clear out the complete signature in one click.

I have changed the style of "Undo last stroke" to style of close button. So in my `jSignature.UndoButton.js`, the style code of "Undo last stroke" button is like below:

```
var undoButtonSytle = 'position:relative;display:none;float: right;margin-right: 5px;outline:0;cursor: pointer;color: rgb(218, 216, 217);font-size: 1.5em;'
                            , $undoButton = $('<i class="fa fa-window-close" style="'+undoButtonSytle+'" aria-hidden="true"></i>').append('<link rel="stylesheet" href="../../css/font-awesome.css" type="text/css" />')
                                .appendTo(this.$controlbarLower)
```

Undo function from `jSignature.UndoButton.js` (there is more code in this file)

```
function attachHandlers(buttonRenderer, apinamespace, extensionName) {
    var $undoButton = buttonRenderer.call(this)

    ;(function(jSignatureInstance, $undoButton, apinamespace) {
        jSignatureInstance.events.subscribe(
            apinamespace + '.change'
            , function(){
                if (jSignatureInstance.dataEngine.data.length) {
                    $undoButton.show()
                } else {
                    $undoButton.hide()
                }
            }
        )
    })( this, $undoButton, apinamespace )

    ;(function(jSignatureInstance, $undoButton, apinamespace) {

        var eventName = apinamespace + '.undo'

        $undoButton.bind('click', function(){
            jSignatureInstance.events.publish(eventName)
        })

        // This one creates new "undo" event listener to jSignature instance
        // It handles the actual undo-ing.
        jSignatureInstance.events.subscribe(
            eventName
            , function(){
                var data = jSignatureInstance.dataEngine.data
                if (data.length) {
                    data.pop()
                    jSignatureInstance.resetCanvas(data)
                }
            }
        )
    })( 
        this
        , $undoButton
        , this.events.topics.hasOwnProperty( apinamespace + '.undo' ) ? 
            // oops, seems some other plugin or code has already claimed "jSignature.undo" event
            // we will use this extension's name for event name prefix
            extensionName :
            // Great! we will use 'jSignature' for event name prefix.
            apinamespace
    )
}
```

I am not very known with Jquery. Can anyone please tell me how should I should I achieve clearing sign in one stroke?

Comment: why don't you call `.jSignature("reset")` to clear out the signature on your button click.

Comment: I am confused with the plugin code and don't know where and what reset code should be added.

Comment: Yea you just have to call .jSignature("reset") or .jSignature("clear") on div , where you have initiated the jSignature widget.

Check jSignatute API doc , https://willowsystems.github.io/jSignature/#/about/

Comment: `.jSignature("reset")` this should be used on button click function. so how do I know which is my button click function? Also in `jSignature.UndoButton.js` or in my html page jSignature's jquery  how should I use `.jSignature("reset")` ?

Answer (score 0):

Can be used in this way.

```
<button id="clear">Clear</button>

$('#clear').click(function () {
$('#signature').jSignature("reset");
});
```